# Where is the bugtracker for `ifconfig` located?

Tags: linux, bugs

Is there an official place to file bugs for the package in which `ifconfig` can be found?

Do most major distributions have their own implementation of the library, or does the library come from one central location?

Comment: some googling pointed no specific bugtracker this seems distro specific

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. try asking to developers

```
 AUTHORS
        Fred N. van Kempen, <waltje@uwalt.nl.mugnet.org>
        Alan Cox, <Alan.Cox@linux.org>
        Phil Blundell, <Philip.Blundell@pobox.com>
        Andi Kleen
```